# Input matrix in verilog

Tags: verilog, hdl

I want to input a n*m (n and m are defined) matrix in verilog (where each element is of 32 bit length), but the compiler gives an error. Is there any direct way to do so? I don't want to write n*m separate input elements.

This is what I tried: `input reg [31:0] matrix [0:9][0:12]`

Anything wrong here?

Comment: any idea about 2D arrays ??  I am using ModelSim for simulating my codes.

Comment: Looks like it compiles on [EDAplayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/SD) with the update in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verilog doesn't support passing multi-dimensional arrays through ports. The feature was added in SystemVerilog.

In EDAplayground, ModelSim runs with SystemVerilog enabled. Even if you remove the `-sv` command option SystemVerilog will still be enabled because the testbench and design have `.sv` file extensions. SystemVerilog Can be disabled in ModelSim with the `-vlog01compat` compile option. Adding this options to Morgan's Example will generate the following error: ([or run here](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/mW))

> ** Warning: (vlog-2644) Conflicting semantics, "-vlog01compat" switch disables SystemVerilog support.
>   -- Compiling module dut
>   ** Error: design.sv(4): 'Port' must not be declared to be an array: matrix.
>   -- Compiling module tb
>   ** Error: testbench.sv(6): (vlog-2110) Illegal reference to memory "data".
>   ** Error: testbench.sv(6): (vlog-2110) Illegal reference to memory "data".
>   ** Warning: testbench.sv(18): (vlog-2644) Conflicting semantics, "-vlog01compat" switch disables SystemVerilog support.

To pass the matrix you need to enable SystemVerilog or pack the matrix into a 1-Dimenion array.

- To enable SystemVerilog, it is recommenced you change your file extension from .v to .sv, Modern simulator will enable SystemVerilog on only this files. Alternatively you could enable the compiler option (most tools it is `-sv`) to force enable SystemVerilog on all Verilog files. The main problem with force enabling is a Verilog variable name may no conflict with a SystemVerilog keyword.
- To translate the matrix to a simple array:

  ```
  parameter DWIDTH=32, XWIDTH=10, YWIDTH=13;
  reg [DWIDTH-1:0] matrix [0:XWIDTH-1][0:YWIDTH-1];
  reg [DWIDTH*XWIDTH*YWIDTH-1:0] flat;
  integer x,y;
  always @* begin
     for (x=0; x<XWIDTH; x=x+1)
       for (y=0; y<YWIDTH; y=y+1)
         flat[(x*XWIDTH+y)*DWIDTH +: DWIDTH] = matrix[x][y];
  end

  reg [DWIDTH-1:0] matrix_rebuild [0:XWIDTH-1][0:YWIDTH-1];
  integer xr,yr;
  always @* begin
     for (xr=0; xr<XWIDTH; xr=xr+1)
       for (yr=0; yr<YWIDTH; yr=yr+1)
         matrix_rebuild[xr][yr] = flat[(xr*XWIDTH+yr)*DWIDTH +: DWIDTH];
  end
  ```

Answer (score 1):

inputs can not be `reg`, change to `wire` or just leave as :

```
input [31:0] matrix [0:9][0:12]
```

I have put an example on [EDAplaygorund](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/SD) which shows the 2D port working in modelsim 10.1d:

---

This will have an input of **4160** bits wide, are you sure this is what you want?

I would suggest Time multiplexing, running with a faster clock and taking in one sample at a time. When clocked synthesis will have to balance that many wires, with any reasonably fast clock for your process you will likely struggle to close timing. I would try to get a clock 130 times faster and load a 32 bit word each clock cycle.

Comment: I need to input atleast these many bits for the module I'm trying to make. Is there any better way to take such big inputs ?

Comment: That sounds better than what I was trying to do...  Still just for enquiry is there a way to input a 2D array?

Comment: I can not see it mentioned in the spec, am sure it is in there though. also added link to question with it compiling on edaplayground. I just removed the `reg` declaration in the input port.

Comment: Are you using a system verilog code in EDAplayground?

Comment: It has SystemVerilog syntax turned on. Think the array style ports was added in SystemVerilog.